# Remove the white Spaces from the Empty column sql server

Tags: sql-server

I Have Temp table which contains the data which is imported from csv file, i want to remove the white space from the empty columns. tried with RTRIM(LTRIM(column)), it is just removing the leading and trailing spaces if string is not null.

Comment: Please, post some sample data and desired result.

Comment: Well LTRIM removes spaces on the left and RTRIM removes trailing spaces. If you want to remove ALL space you need to use REPLACE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use `REPLACE`:

```
SELECT REPLACE(' Test done ', ' ', '')
```

Or cascade of `REPLACE`'s:

```
DECLARE @text nvarchar(MAX)=N' Line test'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'done ';
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@text, ' ', ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')
```

The latter removes space, line feed and carriage return characters. Just expand expression to remove more white characters (i.e. tab).

Comment: Just to mention it: upcoming version will bring [`TRANSLATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt775084.aspx) to avoid `REPLACE`cascades...

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna go out on a lim here and assume you want to change the values imported from the csv to `NULL` if they only contain white spaces or empty strings.

If I'm right, this should do the trick:

```
SELECT NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(ColumnName)), '') As ColumnName
```